# Action doesnt in android tablet

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image: in handset the action bar working]

[image: While in tablet sw600dp and sw720dp the action bar doesnt appear]

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    if (isTablet && config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            || isPhone) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(false);

    }else if(isTabletLarge){
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(true);

    }else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(true);
    }


    return true;
}
```

here is my code for oncreateoptionmenu!

Comment: Looks like a Holo style in your frst screenshot and pre-Holo in the second. You need to post the Manifest and styles you are using. If I'd hazard a guess, you probably want to use ActionBarActivity and the styles from the support library.

Comment: @ci_                                                                    
sir here my manifest




 android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: check this tutorial  http://tech-papers.org/android-working-with-action-bar/

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the API Level and theme of your Emulator. Your current view shows that your emulator setting is not allowing Action Bar.

But hopefully in real device (Tab/phone that supports Action Bar) will show it.